# Error in ranger - User interrupt or internal error

Tags: r

I really need help. I am doing my thesis and can not get this code to work...

I am trying to create a random forest model with ranger in R Markdown, but get this error:

Error: mtry can not be larger than number of variables in data. Ranger will EXIT now.
Error in ranger(formula = Lift ~ ., data = train_cheese, num.trees = 500,  :
User interrupt or internal error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnzWt.png)

Comment: The error says: "mtry can not be larger than number of variables in data". Apparently the value you passed to mtry is bigger than the number of columns of your data and that's not allowed.

Comment: You will make it much eaiser for people to help you if you share a reproducible example of your data by pasting the output of ``dput(head(train_cheese))`` into your question and paste the error message directly into the question rather than an image. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your grid is not organized in the right way. The best approach to build a tuning grid is via `expand.grid`. this function create a data frame from all combinations of the supplied vectors. Look at this example with the `iris` dataset:

```
library(ranger)
data("iris")
grid <- expand.grid(mtry=2:4,min.node.size=seq(0.1,1,0.2),sample.size=seq(0.1,1,0.2))
for (i in 1:nrow(grid)) {
  model <- ranger(Species~.,
                  data=iris,
                  num.trees = 100,
                  mtry=grid$mtry[i],
                  min.node.size = grid$min.node.size[i],
                  sample.fraction =grid$sample.size[i],
                  seed=123,
                  write.forest = T)
  
  grid$OOB[i] <- sqrt(model$prediction.error)
}
```

which give me this output:

```
head(grid)

  mtry min.node.size sample.size       OOB
1    2           0.1         0.1 0.2000000
2    3           0.1         0.1 0.2309401
3    4           0.1         0.1 0.2160247
4    2           0.3         0.1 0.2000000
5    3           0.3         0.1 0.2309401
6    4           0.3         0.1 0.2160247
```